# Pandas reshape columns to time-series rows

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, reshape

I have a pandas dataframe (unhappily with duplicates...)

```
Date        Partner   Value
2017-02-01  Partner1  150
2017-03-01  Partner1  170
2017-02-01  Partner2  160
2017-03-01  Partner2  185
2017-02-01  Partner1  40
2017-03-01  Partner1  90
```

Which I want to reshape by partners, looking like this:

```
Partner    2017-02-01   2017-03-01
Partner1   150          170
Partner2   160          185
Partner1   40           90
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer I needed:

```
series = pd.pivot_table(data, values="Value", index="Partner", columns="Date")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution:

Source DF:

```
In [143]: df
Out[143]:
         Date   Partner  Value
0  2017-02-01  Partner1    150
1  2017-02-01  Partner1    199   # NOTE: duplicated `Date` & `Partner`
2  2017-03-01  Partner1    170
3  2017-02-01  Partner2    160
4  2017-03-01  Partner2    185
```

Solution:

```
In [144]: df.groupby(['Partner','Date'])['Value'].mean().unstack().rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, 1)
Out[144]:
          2017-02-01  2017-03-01
Partner1       174.5       170.0
Partner2       160.0       185.0
```

Comment: This does not work, as `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: @Laurent, could you provide a reproducible data set?

Comment: No, I can't for business reasons, but the issue was that some of the "Partner" names were duplicates, and it made your alternative solution fail.


Using your method on a de-duplicated table worked perfectly.


The pivot_table, however, was not bothered.

Comment: @Laurent, i wasn't talking about real data... I've updated solution, so it'll work with duplicates as well...